# Как это сделать на bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

И как эта штука называется когда свайпается вправо каждые n секунд и можно нажимать на срелочки[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Да это же [carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/), вот пример из документации к bootstrap 4

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block " src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW9Md.png" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block " src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW9Md.png" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block " src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW9Md.png" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```